# How to drop the voltage slightly (~100mV) for a MCU mostly in deep sleep?

Tags: power-supply, low-power, low-voltage

How to drop the voltage by a low value (let's say <150mV) without wasting current to supply a microcontroller that spend most of its time in deep sleep mode?

I'm working on a board with a microcontroller that will accept up to 3.6V as supply voltage but LiFePO<sub>4</sub> and Li/SOCl<sub>2</sub> can go slightly higher when fully charged (or during charge for LiFePO<sub>4</sub>). The microcontroller uses ~10μA during deep sleep and can use up to 500mA (mostly spikes) when active and transmitting over WiFi (ESP32).

I know that I can use an LDO with a low quiescent current but I am curious if there are better/cheaper alternatives. For example, I thought about using the drop voltage of a Schottky diode.

Comment: This can't reasonably be answered without information about the minimum/maximum current draw of your circuit. You could also consider using a different microcontroller. Probably an LDO is your best bet.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I edited my question.

Comment: The MAX 600x family of shunt regulators has a 1uA typical 0.5 uA min operating (Cathode) current. https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6006A-MAX6009B.pdf  Two of appropriate voltage in series may allow you low drain mode to work OK, switching to another mode on throttle-up. || A [S1318 family regulator](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/voltage_regulator/S1318_E.pdf)   can have 55 nA drain, 0.054V dropout [!!!] and bearable cost.  (About $US1) | There are "any number" of regulator rated at 100 mA output and well under 0.1V dropout and sub uA Iq. |

Comment: 5 x 100 mA capable regulators in parallel would give you 500 mA capability at about 0.5 uA iQ and about $3 cost.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to have two independent connections to the supply voltage, one being used for low power mode and another one for a high power mode according to the following:

Right before driving the MCU into deep sleep mode, the active low pin `_ACTIVE` can be disabled (high), thus turning the PFET \$M1\$ off. This means, that the MCU will be supplied by the highly ohmic path formed by \$R_2\$ and \$R_1\$. This voltage devider must be designed to simultaneously provide a voltage smaller or equal than \$3.6V\$, and a current of approximately \$20\mu A\$ for example (just enough to keep the MCU up and running). Once you want to wake up the MCU, the pin `_ACTIVE` can be enabled (low) and the PFET will be turned on. Since it has a very low \$R_{DS,ON}\$, the highly ohmic path will be bypassed. The additional voltage drop that you require can be achieved by selecting a schottky diode with an appropriate forward voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWPwKB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Both of those batteries (more the LiFePO<sub>4</sub> than the Li/SOCl<sub>2</sub>) have useful charge below the 3.3V required for a microcontroller. If you were hoping to squeeze the absolute maximum amount of battery life possible, you could use a buck-boost converter. They [exist](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63001.pdf) in small form factors and high efficiencies. Otherwise, use an LDO. You probably could use a schottky diode but you probably shouldn't. The forward drop of a Schottky is dependent on temperature and current, and is not tightly controlled like an LDO. They're also about the same price as an LDO (@ qty 1 on digikey, the [cheapest Schottky diode](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/RB520S30T5G/RB520S30T5GOSCT-ND/5213385) is $.13 and the [cheapest LDO](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MIC5504-3-3YM5-TR/576-4764-1-ND/4864028) is $.11).

Comment: Assuming you have a microcontroller with a strict 3.3v input voltage. Most will work down to 2.x. Only issue is ensuring the clock you want to work at works at the lower voltage.

Comment: Low quiescent current LDO are typically more expensive and there is still a not negligible quiescent current.